Apply a command to all cells of a specific row of a table
Consider the following MWE
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\def\foo#1{#1}
\begin{table}
   \centering
   \begin{tabular}{cc}
     \foo{a} & \foo{a} \\
     b       & b
   \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}

The command \foo is applied to all the elements of the first row of the table.
I would like to define a command \applyfoo so that I can just simply write:
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\def\foo#1{#1}
\begin{table}
   \centering
   \begin{tabular}{cc}
     \applyfoo   a & a \\
                 b & b
   \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}

I spent some time on this site trying to find a solution, but I could only find solutions for cases where braces are not needed, like \bfseries.

With tabularray you can use option cmd={<command>}, that executes <command> for the cell text.
With row{1}={<options>} you can apply <options> to the first row. Of course, you could choose any row/column/cell you like or also a range of them or all the table.
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\def\foo#1{#1}
\begin{table}
   \centering
   \begin{tblr}{
     colspec={cc},
     row{1}={cmd=\foo}
     }
     a & a \\
     b & b
   \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}

Here an example with a command with some visible effect on the text:
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\def\foo#1{before \textcolor{red}{#1} after}
\begin{table}
   \centering
   \begin{tblr}{
     colspec={cc},
     row{1}={cmd=\foo}
     }
     W & X \\
     Y & Z
   \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}


